# How to populate Spinner from a Array string[]

Tags: android, arrays, string, android-spinner

How to populate a Spinner from Array string[]

Example:

String[] **items** = new String[] {"uno", "due", "tre"};

*sp* = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
*sp* <<--- ADD **items** Array

thanks

marco

Comment: what is the difficulty you are facing?

Comment: how to add dynamically items to spinner.
In my case items are store from in String Array.

Answer (score 7):

try this.

```
 sp.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items));
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need to create a new ArrayAdapter using the String[] items as the source data and then sp.setAdapter to the newly created ArrayAdapter.

References:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html